# How to find the mean of values in a particular column that have duplicate timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, mean

**Original dataframe**

| Timestamp | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19:26:01 | 27 | 55.2 | Earth |
| 19:26:01 | 20 | 54.5 | Jupiter |
| 19:26:02 | 20 | 56.2 | Mars |
| 19:26:02 | 24 | 53.6 | Venus |

**Required output**

| Timestamp | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19:26:01 | 23.5 | 54.85 | Earth |
| 19:26:02 | 22 | 54.9 | Mars |

I have tried using
df = df.groupby('Timestamp', as_index=False).mean()

Other columns of df have non-numeric values due to which I guess I got the following warning:

FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrameGroupBy.mean is deprecated. In a future version, numeric_only will default to False. Either specify numeric_only or select only columns which should be valid for the function.

Is there a way to get the mean of "numeric_only" columns while keeping the first value of the non-numeric value of the duplicate row?

Comment: `df.groupby('Timestamp', as_index=False).agg({'A': 'mean', 'B': 'mean', 'C': 'first'})` or for a programmatic version craft a dictionary first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small DataFrame, you can use:

```
(df.groupby('Timestamp', as_index=False)
   .agg({'A': 'mean', 'B': 'mean', 'C': 'first'})
)
```

If you need a programmatic way:

```
agg_funcs = {c: 'mean' if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df[c]) else 'first'
             for c in df} 
# {'Timestamp': 'first', 'A': 'mean', 'B': 'mean', 'C': 'first'}

df.groupby('Timestamp', as_index=False).agg(agg_funcs)
```

Output:

```
  Timestamp     A      B      C
0  19:26:01  23.5  54.85  Earth
1  19:26:02  22.0  54.90   Mars
```